# iOS Swift 4 OAuth

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, oauth

I writing an app in Swift 4 that uses the [Discogs API](https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:authentication,header:authentication-discogs-auth-flow). As such, I require a user to have access to personal data on their Discogs account, so I am authenticating against their API using [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift). Currently, I am able to kick off the auth flow, sign in and return the an `oauthToken` and the `oauthTokenSecret`

Making a subsequent request to their `https://api.discogs.com/oauth/identity` I am returned a user object, so I am happy at this point I can sign in and make authenticated requests.

However, I do not understand how I can check if a user is authenticated when the app first starts up. Currently, I am not storing the response, instead I am making a call to the identity endpoint in nested callback

```
import UIKit
import OAuthSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let oauthSwift = OAuth1Swift(
        consumerKey: "foo",
        consumerSecret: "bar",
        requestTokenUrl: "https://api.discogs.com/oauth/request_token",
        authorizeUrl: "https://www.discogs.com/oauth/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://api.discogs.com/oauth/access_token"
    )

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        kickOffAuthFlow()

    }

    fileprivate func kickOffAuthFlow() {

        oauthSwift.authorizeURLHandler = SafariURLHandler(viewController: self, oauthSwift: oauthSwift)

        guard let callbackURL = URL(string: "foo.bar.boobaz:/oauth_callback") else { return }

        oauthSwift.authorize(withCallbackURL: callbackURL, success: { (credential, response, parameters) in
            _ = self.oauthSwift.client.get("https://api.discogs.com/oauth/identity", success: { (response) in
                guard let dataString = response.string else { return }
                print(dataString)
            }, failure: { (error) in
                print("error")
            })
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

What is best practice in this case? How should I store these tokens and how should I ensure once the user is logged in, they aren't forced to log in the next time the app is opened (providing the token hasn't expired, however that is a separate issue I am prepared to handle at a later point)

Coming from a web development background, I was able to just store a token in session storage, on load I would then check the exp on the token and request a new one or take some other action.

I have not quite grasped how this works in iOS development yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to store access token in local.

1. UserDefault
2. Keychain

**1. UserDefault**

Use ***UserDefault*** to store token in memory. When the app gets launch, check if the token is stored in userdafault. UserDefault is used as short memory storage where you can store small data. It remains in memory if you kill the app.

```
    let tokenIdentifier = "TokenIdentifier"
    func storeAccessToken(token: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: tokenIdentifier)
    }

    func checkUserLogin() {
        if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: tokenIdentifier) != nil {
            print("User is Login")
        }
        else {
            print("User need to login")
        }
    }
```

check this for learn more about userdefault

https://swift3tutorials.com/swift-3-user-defaults/

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults

**2. Keychain**

Userdefault is not secure. An access token is a sensitive information which should be stored in a secure place. So storing the access token in user default is not the correct choice. You must store access token in the keychain. Use **SwiftKeychainWrapper** pod to store token in Keychain.

```
    let tokenIdentifier = "TokenIdentifier"
    func storeAccessToken(token: String) {
        KeychainWrapper.standard.set(token, forKey: tokenIdentifier)
    }

    func checkUserLogin() {
        let token: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: tokenIdentifier)
        if token != nil {
            print("User is Login")
        }
        else {
            print("User need to login")
        }
    }
```

Comment: **1-** "Use UserDefault for store token in memory" seems to be *incorrect*, user defaults stored in disk, it saved as a plist which you could access it somehow. **2-** Based on the first point, saving sensitive data like tokens and password should *not* be done directly in the userdefaults (since it is publicly accessible); It should be in the keychain instead.

Comment: For security you can store token in Keychain. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/securing-user-data-with-keychain-for-ios-e720e0f9a8e2

Comment: Hitesh, could you please edit your answer to include the Keychain docs and I can then accept it. I found the link you pasted very helpful and have achieved what I needed now, thank you :)